# Invalid int when parsing integer with "+"

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I just got this error today for one of my android applications.

Device nexus 7 with android 4.2.2

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "+5"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at sk.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After mapping the error log i found that the error comes from this exact line of code.

```
EditText itemBonus = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.item_bonus);
String itemBonusString = itemBonus.getText().toString().trim();
if (itemBonusString.equals("")) {
    itemBonusString = "0";
}
item.setItemBonus(Integer.parseInt(itemBonusString));
```

**BUT**
I have defined the editext as shown below

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/item_bonus"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="numberSigned" />
```

I know that when the inputType is numberSigned the keyboard allows only decimal numbers or the minus symbol like "2" or "-3".

First i wondered HOW the user managed to insert the plus sign in the edittext because after all it is not allowed.
So i checked in the emulator and unfortunately i found that even though the + sign is not allow in pre 4.2.2 versions of android. In 4.2.2 and later the user can add the plus sign from the onscreenkeyboard in an EditText with inputType="numberSigned". which unfortunately causes an error in parseInt

So after explaining the problem i wonder if anyone have found a workaround, or can give a valid solution for all versions of android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Invalid int when parsing integer with “+”

Simly `Integer.parseInt()` is not able to recognize `+` symbol. You have two options:

- remove this symbol before with `yourString.replace("+", "");`
- you can use DecimalFormat with pattern `+#;-#`

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the `+` before parsing it:

`item.setItemBonus(Integer.parseInt(itemBonusString.replaceAll("+", "")));`